# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop even after giving the keys

Tags: reactjs

The script.js file

```
const ingredients = [
  { id: 1, name: "Milk" },
  { id: 2, name: "Sugar" },
  { id: 3, name: "Powder" },
];

const IngredientsList = ({ ingredients }) => {
  return React.createElement(
    "ul",
    { className: "some" },
    ingredients.map((ing) =>
    React.createElement("li", { key: `${ing.id}` }, ing.name)
  );
};

let h2 = React.createElement("h2", { className: "some" }, "Making Tea");

ReactDOM.render(
  [h2, React.createElement(IngredientsList, { ingredients })],
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The code above shows the usual unique key problem in the console even after giving proper keys to the `<li>` element.

I am using these libraries in html. The whole index.html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What can be the solution? Using JSX solves it but would like to know the reason for this warning when using `React.createElement()`. Thanks.

Edit. When I changed ->

```
ReactDOM.render(
      [h2, React.createElement(IngredientsList, { ingredients })],
```

to

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(IngredientsList, { ingredients }),
```

without the array [h2,...], the error disappeared!.

Comment: Using the map index as the key is an anti pattern. Consider checking google for that to find tons of articles on how this should be fixed.

Comment: @0stone0. I have changed the question. Assume that a Rest call gave me an array of objects. Still the warning remains..

Comment: Im unable to reproduce the error. Could you add a [mre] ?

Comment: @0stone0. I have edited the question and have provided both the script.js and the index.html. I am using live server vsc extension to open the page at localhost:5500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting doesn't come from your `<li>` elements, but from your `ReactDOM.render()` method, as there you're rendering an **array** of items (`h2` and `IngredientLsList`), and React needs a key prop **for each item** when it renders arrays.

Giving a *key* to both `h2` and `IngredientsList` components will solve the warning:

```
// give a key prop to h2
let h2 = React.createElement("h2", { key: "someKey_1", className: "some" }, "Making Tea");

// give a key prop to IngredientsList
ReactDOM.render(
  [h2, React.createElement(IngredientsList, { key: "someKey_2", ingredients })],
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

You can find this [here in React docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings)

Comment: here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-water-75cu1e?file=/src/index.js works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

You should never use map index as a key, since keys have to be static values. If you use indexes you basically are defeating the very same purpose of key optimization during the reconciliation. Try with `key={ing}`.

EDIT: `ing` has to be a string obviously, as @Nick Vu highlighted.

Comment: That will cause more problems because the key is a string. Your value will be converted to `[object Object]` for all keys

Comment: @NickVu is right. When I gave { key: ing }, it gave me more warnings.. "Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`."

Comment: @Nick Vu, of course depending on your data, i meant ing as "name of the ingredient" (which should be unique). He could use ing.id in his case...

Answer (score -1):

Can you try converting your code into these set of code:
it seems to work to me

```
React.createElement("ul", null, ingredients.map(ing => React.createElement("li", {
  key: ing.id
}, ing.name)));
```

to

```
<ul>
      {ingredients.map((ing) => (
        <li key={ing.id}>{ing.name}</li>
      ))}
</ul>
```

and

```
const H2Holder = () => {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h2", null, "Make some tea");
};
```

to

```
const H2Holder = () => {
  return <h2>Make some tea</h2>;
};
```

then on the App.js

```
function App() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(H2Holder, null), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(SubComponent, null));
}
```

to

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <H2Holder></H2Holder>
      <SubComponent />
    </>
  );
}
```

then on the Index.js just import the App and render it

```
ReactDOM.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(React.StrictMode, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(App, null)), document.getElementById('root'));
```

to

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image: Here is the result]

Comment: As I have described in the question, when using JSX and function components, this warning doesn't arise. This happens only when using ReactDOM.render([])... The array is the problem...